# How to center thumbnails for all screen-sizes?

Tags: html, css, screen-size

```
body{
    width:auto;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1980px;
    min-width:334px;    
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

This is my code. I need thumbnails to be in the center for all screen resolutions. But I can't do it. I even tried tag. It didn't work either. What should I do?

http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/galeriler/kopya.php  for sample page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good article on centering anything with css:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/

Answer (score 1):

```
#gallery { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Horizontally centering a block-level element like a `div` simply requires specifying a width and setting the horizontal margin to auto.

Answer (score 0):

This should be used to center the complete webpage

```
   body {
      position: relative;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #333;
   }
```